# Node to String: Changing the String to Reverse

Tags: java, list, reverse

The problem I am having is that I making a Node into a string and I have accomplished that much but what I am having trouble is now making it show in reverse. Its a list and I have tried a few methods but it keeps showing the order as if it wasn't in reverse. A code example would be appreciated.

Here is my CODE:

```
public void reverseDisplay(){       
    Node currentNode = head;
    while(currentNode != null){
        String out = "";
        out = out + currentNode.getItem() + " ";
        System.out.print(out);
        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: you appended the items on the end of "out" so it would print [item1, item2, item3...] whereas you wanted to achieve [itemN, ..., item2, item1]. See my solution below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track (untested but should work):

```
public void reverseDisplay(){       
  Node currentNode = head;
  String out = "";

  while(currentNode != null){

    out = currentNode.getItem() + " " + out; // instead of out + currentNode.getItem() + " ";
    currentNode = currentNode.getNext();

  }
  System.out.println(out);
}
```

Comment: Just because it took me some time to spot the difference: `out = out + currentNode.getItem() + " ";` has been changed to `out = currentNode.getItem() + " " + out;` ;)

Comment: @Thomas: Oh thank you, now it works. I just moved the out, outside the while loop so it can work with the println(out). Thank you very much I see what I needed to do. I needed it to call out the out again.

Comment: @ClarkStewart if this answer helped you, feel free to reward Christopher with an accept ;)

Comment: yeah sorry, i should have commented on that

Comment: @Thomas: I will, its just telling me that I have to wait 4 minutes in till I can accept the answer.

Comment: @Christopher: Its no problem and no need to apologize, I should be thanking you my friend. Thank you very much.